# Create Interactive Image in android

Tags: android, image-processing

I have images that want to interactive in android, please help me how I can make interactive image in android, I'm new user on this site, may be site is not allow me to post image.

My scenario is, I have 10 chairs around table, and I want user interactive with chair (Click able) and goes to other screen. I'm new to android. Please explain how I can create interactive images for my apps.

Here is an image that helps you understand my scenario:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set [OnTouchListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.htm) to your image view with `onTouchEvent` method like this one:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
    x = event.getX() + this.getLeft();
    y = event.getY() + this.getTop();
   // check if (x,y) is on chair and do other staff
}
return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

(x,y) is a point on picture which was clicked. Save ranges of picture's point which are on chairs. Than just check on which one you've clicked and do appropriate staff.

Comment: I think using touch event for so many objects will be very complicated. As user want to perform separate operations on every chair click.

Answer (score 0):

keep all the chair images as separate ImageButton and use on Click listener for image views.
Like for any chair x

```
ImageButton xchair = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.xchair);
xchair.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                **Call intent for calling another activity here.**
            }
        });
```